# 3 attempt to log in using a value of user and password comes from MySQL Database and how to return to a page using javascript

Tags: javascript, mysql, asp.net

i am creating an Log in form .. while the user attempt 3 times error it was automatically close ...and another one the document that i want to print is already done but sad to say i get an error after clicking save to folder

here is my code

code for 3 attempt

```
using System;
etc...

namespace SchoolPortal
{
    public partial class registration : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        static int attempts = 3;

        MySqlConnection conn = 
            new MySqlConnection(@"Data Source=localhost;
                Uid=root;Pwd=secret;Database=payroll_system;");

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Session["e"] != null && Session["password"] != null)
            {
                Response.Redirect("employeelist.aspx");
            }
        }

        protected void btnLog_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string value;
            int j = 0;
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
            using (MySqlConnection conn = 
                new MySqlConnection(@"Data Source=localhost;
                    Uid=root;Pwd=secret;Database=payroll_system;"))
            {
                conn.Open();
                MySqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * from employee_info where password ='" + txtPass.Text + "' and employee_ID='" + txte.Text + "'";
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(dt);

                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    Session["e"] = txte.Text;
                    Session["password"] = txtPass.Text;
                    Response.Redirect("employeelist.aspx");
                }
                conn.Close();
                attempts = 0;
                if (txte.Text != Session["e"] && 
                    txtPass.Text != Session["password"])
                {    
                    if((attempts < 3 ))
                        for (int i = 0; i <= j; i++) ;
                            j = dt.Rows.Count + 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    Label1.Text = (" Check your Email or Password "
                        + "as well as your Employee Identification if " 
                        + "Correct then TRY AGAIN You have '" + 
                        j + "' tries left.") + 1;
                }

                if (txte.Text == "" && txtPass.Text == "")
                {
                    Label1.Text = " Fill the need information";
                    txte.Focus();
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and here is my code for printing document that is not return to page

```
   <td align="left">

             <button onclick="myFunction()">PRINT</button>
              <script>
                  function myFunction() {
                      window.print();
                      return;
                  }
              </script>

               &nbsp;</td>
```

Comment: Look for `ClientScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock` to add js from code behind.

Comment: Tnx i try to search it

Comment: Wait wer i gonna put this code?

Comment: Sad to sayIt doent work